# How can I change the title of a dynamic page?

Tags: jquery-mobile, dynamic-pages

I have a jQuery Mobile app that's just like the dynamic page sample from the jQuery Mobile documentation http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/dynamic-samples/sample-reuse-page.html.

Everything works fine, but just as in the example I can't get the page titles to change accordingly to the requested page. On the basis of the example: When you click the category Colors in the Categories section, the new page has the title Colors, but when you go back and then select Vehicles, the page title is still Colors. How can I fix this?

I tried `$page.attr('data-title', category.name)` in the `showCategory` function but it won't work. Any ideas?

Comment: the jquery example page works fine for me, both in chrome and my android phone.

Comment: Seriously? I always get http://i.imgur.com/aBvNr.jpg, the same for firefox (both mobile and desktop)

Comment: Ah you are right, the tabs on my chrome were so stretched I didn't noticed.. ugh.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use something like this -

```
$("title").html(category.name);
```

Comment: jquery mobile has a built in page title system ... original post mentions the 'data-title' attribute. So although your answer is correct from an html point of view, it is not correct from a jqm pov. Doing this on a jqm site  would basically be a conflict.

Comment: You can try something like this -
$("#div-id").data("title", "New Page title");

That's worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the behaviour you're describing in the example. However, to change the title wouldn't this do the job?

```
document.title = category.name;
```